# Terminally incomplete downloads

Tags: download, bittorrent

It often happens when I'm downloading music -- usually classical -- I'll get 99+% of the file and the download stops. I've tried deleting and reloading the torrent only to get the same result. I've tried accessing the torrent at various times over several months and it still never completes downloading.

The problem is that often the missing 0.05% that fails to download is at a critical point in the music. In a 90 minute piece this translates into 27 seconds -- a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First possibility that comes to mind - none of the seeders or peers actually had full 100% in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem is that a *full* filename, i.e., *path + filename*, is too long. Look at some missing files in the torrent to check their length. Some torrent/magnet clients may have their own file length limitation, e.g., [qbittorrent](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/issues/349).

Workarounds:

- Enable long filenames in the OS, e.g., for [Windows NTFS](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-10/enable-long-file-name-support-windows-10). Linux may have 255 character limits in ext*n* file systems. Macs may have a [255 character *filename* limit, but allow an additional long path](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86611/does-os-x-enforce-a-maximum-filename-length-or-character-restriction).
- Download to a folder near root, e.g., *C:\tmp*, rather than to one in your own *Download* folder.
- *If* the torrent client offers a renaming facility ([perhaps µTorrent?](https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/29688-file-names-too-long-to-download/)), use it to truncate filenames.